# Are there multiple copies of each document in my single couchdb node?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

I have a single instance of couch running (version 2.1.1). In the configuration settings for clustering it is set to have 3 replicas of each document (n=3).

Are there actually 3 copies of each document on my single instance? If so how is that beneficial? In turn, if that makes sense to change to say 1 instead is it as simple as changing that value in the configuration and restarting couch or do I need to do something to eliminate the existing replicas?